# Jquery help for html flyout menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I have this html code and I'm trying using jquery to activate a flyout menu without any success. Since the menu is created automatically, I have no way to modify the html code.
Any jquery gurus around that can help with this issue?

Thank you in advance :)

html code:

```
<div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
<ul class="root static">
<li class="static">
<a class="static menu-item" href="">
<span class="additional-background">
<span class="menu-item-text">HOME</span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="static dynamic-children">
<a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" href="">
<span class="additional-background">
<span class="menu-item-text">ABOUT</span>
</span>
</a>
<ul class="dynamic" style="">
<li class="dynamic">
<a class="dynamic menu-item" href="">
<span class="additional-background">
<span class="menu-item-text">WHO WE ARE</span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="dynamic">
<a class="dynamic menu-item" href="">
<span class="additional-background">
<span class="menu-item-text">OUR STRATEGY</span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="dynamic">
<a class="dynamic menu-item" href="">
<span class="additional-background">
<span class="menu-item-text">OUR CLIENTS</span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('body').ready(function() {


            $('li.dynamic-children').hover(function() {

                $(this).find('ul.dynamic').slideToggle(); 
            });
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: try $(document).ready(function() {... });

Comment: what is the exact problem? the code seems to be working fine somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery code was correct! I had to modify it a bit to be compatible with the current CSS in SharePoint. The final code (even though not optimized) is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

         $('li.dynamic-children').find('ul.dynamic').css("display","none");

}); </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.dynamic-children').on('hover',function () {
     $(this).addClass("hover");
         $(this).find('ul.dynamic').slideToggle();
         $(this).find('ul.dynamic').css('left','-1px');
         $(this).find('ul.dynamic').css('top','43px');
    });
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, just use `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.dynamic-children').on('hover',function () {
         $(this).find('ul.dynamic').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/z2JEf/)